# fatal: Could not read from remote repository (through ssh)

Tags: git, aws-codecommit

When I am trying to push code on AWS code-commit repo using this command

//error comes from below second statement.

```
git add remote codecommit ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Test-codecommit-repo

git push codecommit develop
```

it show me the error like this :

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

and my ~/.ssh/config file looks like this:

```
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
User AP***************UQ
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa
```

This key is perfect there is no error to access repo using this key

I only want to access my repo over ssh not over https.
what should I do now ??

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Test-codecommit-repo
```

This seems to have to be following:

```
ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/Test-codecommit-repo
```